# VPN connecetd but unable to access network/ browse local site

Tags: networking

We are using Ubuntu 14.04, Vpn connected but unable to access network & browse site hosted on VPN network.

Comment: Can you put output from command `route -n` when is vpn connected?

Answer (score 0):

To enable IPv4 forward. Change /etc/sysctl.conf file, add forward rule below.

```
# sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Uncomment the line

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then reload the configuration

```
sudo sysctl -p
```